# Export single values from OMS to an excel sheet

Tags: excel, spss

I done a reliability analysis in SPSS. Now I want to export single values (ICC, Cronbachs Alpha, F-value, ...) in a custom table in an excel sheet. Anyone got any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The standard export facilities in Statistics, whether using OMS or OUTPUT EXPORT from the Viewer, handle entire tables, not individual elements.  You could write a WinWrap Basic script to access individual cells from the Viewer and use the Excel VBA library to populate cells in an Excel file as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The OMS facility captures an entire table, but sends it to a dataset that you define. You can then open that dataset, if there is more than one case - select only the case that has your data, and save the right column to Excel.
For example, you mentioned Cronbach's Alpha:

```
DATASET DECLARE  reliability.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Reliability'] SUBTYPES=['Reliability Statistics']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_
   OUTFILE='reliability'.
```

`RELIABILITY 
    /VARIABLES=  Q1 to Q8 
    /SCALE('ALL VARIABLES')ALL
    /MODEL=ALPHA
    /SUMMARY=TOTAL .`

```
OMSEND.
dataset activate Reliability.
SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE='Cronbachs Alpha in Excel.xlsx'
  /TYPE=XLS   /VERSION=12   /MAP   /REPLACE   /FIELDNAMES   /CELLS=VALUES
  /KEEP=CronbachsAlpha.
```